# How to add Identity-based policy to authorize Cognito-Identity access to Amazon Lex Bot? I am also trying to add resource-based policy to Lex Bot

Tags: reactjs, bots, amazon-cognito, amazon-lex

I am making a chatbot in react application. I have used `react-lex-plus` npm package.
In the LexChat component, I have entered my bot alias. I have created a new identity pool id.
But after running it locally, I am getting

```
   AccessDeniedException: User: arn:aws:sts::myAccountId:assumed-role/Cognito_LiveAssistanceBotIdUnauth_Role/CognitoIdentityCredentials is not authorized to perform: lex:PostText on resource: arn:aws:lex:us-east-1:myAccountIdbot:LiveAssistanceBot:$LATEST because no identity-based policy allows the lex:PostText action
```

I don't know where to update identity-based policy. I am also trying to setup resource-based policy for Lex Bot.

```
    {
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "LiveAssitanceBotId",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": [
          "cognito-identity.amazonaws.com"
        ]
      },
      "Action": [
        "lex:RecognizeText",
        "lex:StartConversation"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:lex:us-east-1:myAccountID_:bot-alias/1AUEAAP4MW/9F7RMYLBSU"
      ],
      "Condition": {
        "StringEquals": {
          "AWS:SourceAccount": "myAccountId_"
        },
        "ArnEquals": {
          "AWS:SourceArn": "arn:aws:cognito-identity:us-east-1:myAccountId_:identitypool/us-east-1:d4a81595-0381-4fbb-ab20-9b76e4143ca1"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

after which I am getting `Internal Error` while creating the policy.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the `lex:PostText` capability to the `Action` section of your policy.

Below is an extract from one of my existing permission policies:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "lex:PostContent",
                "lex:PostText",
                "lex:PutSession",
                "lex:GetSession",
                "lex:DeleteSession",
                "lex:RecognizeText",
                "lex:RecognizeUtterance",
                "lex:StartConversation"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```